# Is this possible to draw a physical size 5 cm * 5 cm square on the iOS device?

Tags: ios

I would like to draw a physically 5cm * 5cm square, instead of using pixel. Instead of getting all the iOS device screen information, is there any generic way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a generic way that is 100% accurate. You would need to compile a database of all the different devices and have an appropriate pixel size figured out ahead of time.